# where to find Phprunner query logs?

Tags: php, mysql, php-generators

i have a project generated by **Phprunner**. some pages respond very slow. then i thought i must inspect generated and executed queries somehow. i'v tried searching trough code and i found lot's of execute functions. i don't know which one is the right execute point.

*i'm using **Phprunner** 9.0 ,Php 5.6 and MySQL.*

where can i find the log file or the right spot for putting logger?

Comment: This might be a better question for the Phprunner forums.

Comment: Dude, turrible speeling, srsly...

Comment: Tnx, Andrew, fixed but it was not that "turrible".